# Additional formatting on a <pre> tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am using `<pre>` tags to preserve long strings of text that include user-entered line breaks.

When the input into the original form was exactly:

> Paragraph 1
>
> Paragraph 2
>
> Paragraph 3

...the pre returns:

> ```
>             Paragraph 1
>
>      Paragraph 2
>
>      Paragraph 3
> ```

In the database, the string is stored:

> "Paragraph 1\r\n\r\nParagraph 2\r\n\r\nParagraph 3."

1. Why is this happening?
2. If the best way to get around this to simply strip out all leading spaces from every newline, how can I accomplish this so it happens across the entire site?

---

Edit: I'm using Ruby on Rails - what would be the code in that case? A particular problem I'm having is with a HAML page.

```
%pre
  - unless condition.blank?
    %br
    - unless @user.show_notes == false
      :preserve
      #{@user.notes}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably indenting your code, eg (PHP example)

```
<pre>
    <?php echo $myString ?>
</pre>
```

Notice the space before the opening `<?php` tag?

Comment: Hi Phil, thank you! That was indeed the problem with my html pages - I'm now trying to figure out the remaining examples in haml (see above).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if using `<pre>` to preserve user entered line breaks is best.

If you are using PHP, just use `nl2br()`.

Then you don't have to worry about indentation in your HTML...